# How to detect if a commit has been done on a remote SVN repo

Tags: python, shell, svn, commit

So I have a SVN repo like svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj_name/trunk/.

I want to check it every 5 minutes if a new commit has been done on it.
my problem is not with the timing, but with the actual detection of a new commit.
How can I get this info?
I need it in either: python or shell cmds.(or anything else and I'll try to figure out)

thanks a lot

Comment: See http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bash fragment stores the newest revision number in a variable:

```
url="svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj_name/"
newest="$( svn log -r HEAD -q "$url" | sed -ne '/^r[0-9]*\).*$/s//\1/p' )"
```

Comment: This is similar to what I've used and works well for me. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of **svn status** command with **--show-updates (-u)** option as described [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

```
svn status -u -v svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj_name/trunk/
```

Note that you can grep output for ***** to find out which files are changed and will be updated when run **svn update**. You can also grep out the latest revision on server (in the last string) and find out commits between these two, e.g. using

```
svn log -rREV1:REV2 svn://xx.xx.xx.xx/proj_name/trunk/
```